# Getting Error while connecting socket IO with my Angular client and node server

Tags: node.js, angular, websocket, socket.io, mean

I'm using node as server and Angular as client and wanted to connect them, got stuck, getting below error

```
(node:42892) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'writeHead' of undefined
    at sendErrorMessage (D:\Server\node_modules\engine.io\lib\server.js:568:7)
    at Server.handshake (D:\Server\node_modules\engine.io\lib\server.js:291:7)
    at Server.onWebSocket (D:\Server\node_modules\engine.io\lib\server.js:460:12)
    at ws.handleUpgrade.conn (D:\Server\node_modules\engine.io\lib\server.js:401:14)
    at WebSocketServer.completeUpgrade (D:\Server\node_modules\ws\lib\websocket-server.js:330:5)
    at WebSocketServer.handleUpgrade (D:\Server\node_modules\ws\lib\websocket-server.js:246:10)
    at verify (D:\Server\node_modules\engine.io\lib\server.js:400:15)
    at Server.verify (D:\Server\node_modules\engine.io\lib\server.js:172:43)
    at Server.handleUpgrade (D:\Server\node_modules\engine.io\lib\server.js:384:10)
    at Server.server.on (D:\Server\node_modules\engine.io\lib\server.js:511:16)
(node:42892) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 8)
```

Below is my code

**Server side**

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const http = require('http');
const server = http.createServer(app);
const { Server } = require("socket.io");
const io = new Server(server);

io.on('connection', (socket) => {
  console.log('a user connected');

  socket.on('disconnect', ()=>{
   console.log('a user disconnected')
  })
});

server.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log('listening on *:3000');
});
```

**Client side**

```
   import * as io from 'socket.io-client';

    @Component({
      selector: 'app-document',
      templateUrl: './document.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./document.component.css']
     })
    export class DocumentComponent implements OnInit {
    
private socket;
  ngOnInit(): void {  
 this.socket = io("http://localhost:3000", {transports: ['websocket', 'polling', 'flashsocket']});     
  }             
}
```

And I'm just calling this service later

Comment: there shouldn't be be a private modifier within a class method

Comment: Other then that do you see any problem or know any reason which lead to this error ?

Comment: considering the error is thrown by the front end, i can see no obvious thing you missed that could lead to that

Comment: correction: there should not be `http://` (as it is more websocket protocol than http although web scoket is built upon http) in front of the url. try `ws://` instead.

Comment: Tried ws://, didn't work. Front end shows no error in console, network tab shows status 101 for websocket

Comment: try to connect through your browser, just go at `http://localhost:3000/socket.io/` and it shall print something on the server

Comment: Browser displayed {"code":0,"message":"Transport unknown"}, server console displayed nothing new.